# Why doesn't GitHub Pages update immediately after you have pushed a binary file in commit?

Tags: github

I see when I pushed a text file to github it reflects immediately but when I am pushing a binary file it takes a minute or so to reflect back. I am using GitHub's API to push my changes. Is there any official docs which explains this?

Any help will be appreciated.

I tried searching and found out like GitHub is not very good with very files but didn't find anything which can explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has nothing to do with text files vs. binary files.

GitHub Pages sites are build using background jobs. Depending on how busy the Pages servers are, how many jobs are ahead of yours, etc. you may see a build happen very quickly, or you may have to wait a while.